# Is America "it" or "she"?

Tags: grammaticality

> America was inhabited by native American Indians thousands of years ago.

What is the appropriate form to use?

> **She** has many different inhabitants today.

> **It** has many different inhabitants today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is correct. If you want to follow political correctness, which is trying to make everything gender-neutral, then *it* will do; if you want to follow tradition, then *she*.

[Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100321022943AALGZp7) had an interesting discussion on this very topic back in 2010.

Comment: Not true if you want to follow established rules. Check any style guide -- AP, Chicago, MLA, etc. "it" is the correct pronoun for non-person entities. We're not talking song lyrics or poetry or personal essays. An English Language learner should not be misled about correct, general purpose writing rules. The reasons that "it" is correct can be debated, but it's a fact.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think this is a matter of being "politically correct". It's more that referring to *countries* with gender-specific pronouns is becoming increasingly less common, [particularly since WW2](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=America%20and%20her%20allies,America%20and%20its%20allies&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

That chart clearly shows the general trend (also reflected with [Britain and her/its allies](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Britain%20and%20her%20allies,Britain%20and%20its%20allies&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)). But in the specific case of **America**, things are further complicated by the fact that in socio-political contexts the "nation-state" is probably more often called **[The] US**. These Google Books figures are interesting...

> *America used its...* [**1770** hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22america%20sent%20her%20soldiers%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22america%20used%20its%22&tbm=bks)
>    *America used her...* [326 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22america%20sent%20her%20soldiers%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22America%20used%20her%22&tbm=bks)
>    *The US used its...* [**5420** hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20us%20used%20its%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22the%20US%20used%20its%22&tbm=bks)
>    *The US used her...* [33 hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20us%20used%20its%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45d85324a3c260ea&q=%22The%20US%20used%20her%22&tbm=bks)

In short, although there's no specific *grammatical* reason to avoid ***she*** in OP's sentence, it certainly strikes me as a somewhat "dated/poetic" usage. I think it's best avoided unless you genuinely intend to "personify" the nation (which doesn't really seem appropriate in OP's case).

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends completely on the context. In general non-fiction, technical, academic, and business writing, using the pronoun "she" with a country is not  appropriate. Use only "it" as a pronoun for things.

In creative writing, including fiction, literary criticism, poetry, and essays (political opinion), the use of a feminine pronoun for certain things, such as ships and countries, can be an effective personalization technique, and is consistent with historical use in English.